# What am I doing wrong? - Visual Basic Events

Tags: vb.net, events, event-handling, c#-to-vb.net

I know that my problem is simple, but I cannot figure out what is wrong with my code. I have this Head First C# book, and I converted the code in VB.NET. I expected that the `catches` subroutine of `Pitcher` class will be called after I clicked a button in my form. But nothing happens.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim myBall As New Ball
        Dim pitcher As New Pitcher
        myBall.OnBallInPlay(New BallEventArgs(10, 20))
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Ball
    Public Event BallInPlay(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As BallEventArgs)
    Public Sub OnBallInPlay(ByVal e As BallEventArgs)
        RaiseEvent BallInPlay(Me, e)
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class BallEventArgs
    Inherits EventArgs
    Dim trajectory As Integer
    Dim distance As Integer
    Public Sub New(ByVal trajectory As Integer, ByVal distance As Integer)
        Me.trajectory = trajectory
        Me.distance = distance
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Pitcher
    Public WithEvents mySender As Ball

    Public Sub catches(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles mySender.BallInPlay
        MessageBox.Show("Pitcher: ""I catched the ball!""")
    End Sub
End Class
```

After invoking `Ball.OnBallInPlay`, `Pitcher.catches` shall listen. Isn't it, or am I missing something obvious and important?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to connect the MyBall event to the pitcher.catches Method. Since the Myball is declared in the method you can't use the WithEvents keyword.

To connect the handler at runtime you use `AddHandler`.

```
Dim myBall As New Ball
Dim pitcher As New Pitcher
AddHandler myBall.BallInPlay, AddressOf pitcher.catches
myBall.OnBallInPlay(New BallEventArgs(10, 20))
```

To disconnect the handler you use `RemoveHandler`.

```
RemoveHandler myBall.BallInPlay, AddressOf pitcher.catches
```

---

**EDIT**

I just understood the problem/missing part. You just need to define the `Pitcher.MySender` since:

- it is declared with `WithEvents` keyword
- and you already invoke the `catches` method via `Handles mySender.BallInPlay`

  ```
  Dim myBall As New Ball
  Dim pitcher As New Pitcher
  pitcher.mySender = myBall
  myBall.OnBallInPlay(New BallEventArgs(10, 20))
  ```

Comment: I see that I didn't need WithEvents and Handles keyword anymore by using AddHandler. Right? and the difference is that the latter is for runtime?

Comment: That gave me a hint. Public Class Pitcher
    Dim myBall As New Ball
    Sub New(ByVal ball As Ball)
        myBall = ball
        AddHandler myBall.BallInPlay, AddressOf Me.catches
    End Sub

    Public Sub catches(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        MessageBox.Show("Pitcher: ""I catched the ball!""")
    End Sub
End Class

Comment: Sorry, it's not readable. The problem is about referencing the 'myBall' to the pitcher object (As what Alex is pointing out). Thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 1):

You define `pitcher`, but you never use it:

```
Dim pitcher As New Pitcher
```

doesn't do anything, therefore, the catches subroutine can never be called as there are no instances of ball.

Additionally, `mySender` is never instantiated and `mySender` and `myBall` refer to different references to a `Ball`

Comment: But how? I thought that the pitcher object will listen anyway without my intervention.

Comment: you would have to call `mySender.ballInPlay` to get the event to be raised. (this is different than calling `myBall.ballInPlay`)

Comment: Sorry, can't really get it. Where should I call 'mySender.ballInPlay' ? In the 'catches' subroutine?